# how use Count in where has Condition by laravel eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have two tables :

**customer table =**

> id,
>       
> score,
>       
> total_buy,
>       
> (this table has many transaction)

**And have a transaction table too**

> customer_id,
>       
> value,
>       
> score,
>       
> created_at,
>       
> (this table blongs to a customer)

i want Search on customer where has 5 transaction and one of them created at 2017/1/1 date
and where customer score and value more than 200 and take 10 row By Random order
(its a lottery system ) 
i Trying this code before ask

```
customer::
      whereHas('transactions', function ($query) use ($last_transaction)
      {
        $query->whereDate('created_at',$last_transaction);
      })
      ->where('total_buy', '>=',$r->minvalue)
      ->where('score', '>=',$r->score)
      ->inRandomOrder()
      ->take($r->customernumber)
      ->get();
```

but i dont know how counting Row subrelation in where has

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `havingRaw()`.

```
customer::
  whereHas('transactions', function ($query) use ($last_transaction)
  {
    $query->havingRaw('COUNT(*) > 4');
  })->
  whereHas('transactions', function ($query) use ($last_transaction)
  {
    $query->whereDate('created_at',$last_transaction);
  })
  ->where('total_buy', '>=',$r->minvalue)
  ->where('score', '>=',$r->score)
  ->inRandomOrder()
  ->take($r->customernumber)
  ->get();
```

This will check for atleast 5 `transactions`. If you need `exact` 5, then use `equal` operator.

Comment: thanks ,but is return where has 5 transaction as created at ... i want check created at in just one of them  and totaly have more than 5 transaction
            $query->havingRaw('COUNT(*) >= 5')->whereDate('created_at',$last_transaction);
i trying this too but work same old

Comment: @MahdiMirhendi I have updated my answer, try it, it should work as you are looking for.

Comment: glad it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

You can pass in extra parameters to `whereHas`.

```
customer::query()
  ->whereHas('transactions', function ($query) use ($last_transaction)
    {
      $query->whereDate('created_at',$last_transaction);
    }, '=', 5)
  ->where('total_buy', '>=',$r->minvalue)
  ->where('score', '>=',$r->score)
  ->inRandomOrder()
  ->take($r->customernumber)
  ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
customer::has('transactions', '>' ,4)
    ->whereHas('transactions', function ($query) use ($last_transaction){
        $query->whereDate('created_at',$last_transaction);
    })
    ->where('total_buy', '>=',$r->minvalue)
    ->where('score', '>=',$r->score)
    ->inRandomOrder()
    ->take($r->customernumber)
    ->get();
```

**Try this, It will also work. You can get data who have at least 5 transactions.**